# Why is querySelector returning null?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code, `alert(el)` outputs `null` and I don't understand why this is happening. If I write just `querySelector('div')` everything is working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        
        div {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: blue;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <div>
            Good bye
        </div>
    </p>
    <script>

        let el = document.querySelector("p div");
        alert(el);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because there is no `div` inside a `p` in your document. _"But why? You can clearly see it in my HTML"_ Yes, but your HTML is invalid, so the browser fixed it for you. A `<p>` cannot contain a `<div>`. Right click on "Good bye" and choose "Inspect", you'll see what your browser did to fix it

Comment: You really helped me. Thank you  very much and sorry for my stupid question I should have seen HTML DOM in the browser but I didn't.